# Counting Binary Strings (No block decompositions)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, bit-strings

The main question goes :

How many binary strings of length $n$ are there that do not contain an odd string of $0$'s as a maximal substring? (So $1001$ is okay but $10001$ is not)

A maximal substring is the substring of maximum length consisting of only $0$'s or only $1$'s.

I encountered this problem on the second page of a introductory book on combinatorics. I know how to solve this using block decompositions but it would be nice to have a combinatorial proof involving some form of counting argument or maybe a recursive formula. I believe there should be such a solution since the book does not assume any block decompositions before this question.

Comment: Is $1110$ OK?  The maximal substring is three $1$s, but the maximal zero substring is one $0$.

Comment: $1110$ is okay according to the wording of the question. (it seems) But something like $111000$ is not okay.

Comment: 1110 is OK, since the maximal substring is 111, and therefore not an odd length string of 0's. I think @IsaacBrowne misinterprets the 'or' in the definition that there need to be two such substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We denote   with

- *run of length $n$* a substring of $n$ consecutive, equal characters  from a binary alphabet $\{0,1\}$.
- A  *maximum run*  of a  string  is a run with maximum  length.
- An $n$-length zero-run is a run consisting of $n$ consecutive $0$s, and a one-run is specified accordingly.

> We derive a generating function for the number $a_n$ of strings  of  length  $n$ having no  odd, maximum zero-run.
>
> To  avoid    ambiguities      we follow OPs comment and allow odd maximum runs of $1$'s together with odd runs of $0$'s as long as they are less in length than the odd maximum run of $1$'s which seems to be a somewhat more challenging problem.
>
> The string $$0111\color{blue}{000}11$$ has an odd maximum zero-run of length $3$ equal to the maximum one-run and is *not admissible*. The string $$\color{blue}{0}111011$$ has an odd maximum zero-run of length $1$ *less than* the maximum one-run of length $3$ and is *admissible*.

We derive the number of admissible words of length $n$ by counting those words which are *not admissible*.  The number of wanted words is $2^n$ minus this quantity. We do so by  deriving a generating function 
\begin{align*}
G^{(=2k+1,\geq 2k+1)}(z)\qquad\qquad\qquad k\geq 0
\end{align*}
The first component of the index gives the maximum run length of $0$'s, the second component gives the maximum run length of $1$'s. So,  $[z^n]G^{(=2k+1,\geq 2k+1)}(z)$ gives the number of words of length $n$ having maximum zero-runs of length $2k+1$ and maximum one-runs of length less or equal to $2k+1$.

> It follows the number $a_n$ of admissible words of length $n$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> a_n=2^n-[z^n]\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}G^{(=2k+1,\geq 2k+1)}(z)\qquad\qquad n\geq 0
> \end{align*}

We build the generating functions $G(z)$ from the generating function of *Smirnov words* also called *Carlitz words*. These are words
with no consecutive equal characters at all. (See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.)

> A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over a binary alphabet is given by
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(1-\frac{2z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}
> \end{align*}

Replacing occurrences of $0$ in a Smirnov word by one up to $2k+1$ zeros generates words having runs of $0$ with length less or equal $2k+1$.
\begin{align*}
z\longrightarrow z+z^2+\cdots+z^{2k+1}=\frac{z\left(1-z^{2k+1}\right)}{1-z}
\end{align*}

> The same can be done with ones and the resulting generating function is
>   \begin{align*}
> G^{(\geq 2k+1,\geq 2k+1)}(z)=\left(1-2\cdot\frac{\frac{z\left(1-z^{2k+1}\right)}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z\left(1-z^{2k+1}\right)}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}
> &=\frac{1-z^{2k+1}}{1-2z+z^{2k+1}}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since we need a generating function counting words having *exactly* $2k+1$ zero-runs we calculate
>   \begin{align*}
> &G^{(=2k+1,\geq 2k+1)}(z)=G^{(\geq 2k+1,\geq 2k+1)}(z)-G^{(\geq 2k,\geq 2k+1)}(z)\\
> &\qquad=\left(1-\frac{\frac{2z\left(1-z^{2k+1}\right)}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z\left(1-z^{2k+1}\right)}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}
> -\left(1-\frac{\frac{z\left(1-z^{2k}\right)}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z\left(1-z^{2k}\right)}{1-z}}
> -\frac{\frac{z\left(1-z^{2k+1}\right)}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z\left(1-z^{2k+1}\right)}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{1-z^{2k+2}}{1-2z+z^{2k+2}}-\frac{(1-z^{2k+1})(1-z^{2k+2})}{1-2z+z^{2k+2}+z^{2k+3}-z^{4k+3}}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{(1-z^{2})(1-z^{2k+2})z^{2k+1}}{(1-2z+z^{2k+2})(1-2z+z^{2k+2}+z^{2k+3}-z^{4k+3})}
> \end{align*}

We finally conclude

> The number $a_n$ of admissible words of length $n$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> a_n&=2^n-[z^n]\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}G^{(=2k+1,\geq 2k+1)}(z)\\
> &=2^n-[z^n]\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}
> \frac{(1-z^{2})(1-z^{2k+2})z^{2k+1}}{(1-2z+z^{2k+2})(1-2z+z^{2k+2}+z^{2k+3}-z^{4k+3})}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   The sequence $(a_n)$ starts with
>   \begin{align*}
> (a_n)_{n\geq 1}=(1,2,5,12,24,\color{blue}{48},95,187,367,724,\ldots)
> \end{align*}

**Example:** Let's calculate  the number $a_6$ of admissible words of length $6$.

According to (1) we obtain the following series expansions (with some help of Wolfram Alpha)
\begin{align*}
G^{(=1,\leq 1)}(z)&=\frac{(1-z)^2(1-z^2)z}{(1-2z+z^2)(1-2z+z^2)}=\frac{(1+z)z}{1-z}\\
&=z+2z^2+2z^3+2z^4+2z^5+\color{blue}{2}z^6+2z^7+2z^8+2z^9+2z^{10}\cdots\\
G^{(=3,\leq 3)}(z)&=z^3+2z^4+5z^5+\color{blue}{12}z^6+25z^7+53z^8+109z^9+220z^{10}\cdots\\
G^{(=5,\leq 5)}(z)&=z^5+\color{blue}{2}z^6+5z^7+12z^8+28z^9+64z^{10}\cdots\\
\end{align*}

We conclude the number $a_6$ is given by
\begin{align*}
a_6&=2^6-[z^6]\sum_{k=0}^2G^{(=k,\leq k)}(z)\\
&=64-[z^6]\left(G^{(=1,\leq 1)}(z)+G^{(=3,\leq 3)}(z)+G^{(=5,\leq 5)}(z)\right)\\
&=64-\color{blue}{2}-\color{blue}{12}-\color{blue}{2}\\
&=48
\end{align*}

The $64-a_6=16$ non-admissible words are

\begin{array}{cccc}
1\color{blue}{0}1010&\color{blue}{0}10101\\
001\color{blue}{000}&101\color{blue}{000}&011\color{blue}{000}&111\color{blue}{000}\\
\color{blue}{000}100&1\color{blue}{000}10&\color{blue}{000}110&01\color{blue}{000}1\\
11\color{blue}{000}1&\color{blue}{000}101&1\color{blue}{000}11&\color{blue}{000}111\\
1\color{blue}{00000}&\color{blue}{00000}1\\
\end{array}